# Loading XML File with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, xml

I have Web Api calls that I make via angular $http ,  What I need to do are some various options.

1. Call Web Api endpoint which will then create an XML file on the file system of which I need to be able to have my Angular application display the XML in another window   -  would this be done a specific way with angular?
2. Like to Also be able to stream in memory the xml to be in angular as a string for me to decide how to parse    thoughts?

I do see code like below, which is "nice" , but I don't want to just convert xml to json

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).factory('DataSource', ['$http',function($http){
            return {
                get: function(file,callback,transform){
                    $http.get( file, {transformResponse:transform} ).

                            success(function(data, status) {
                                console.log("Request succeeded", data);
                                callback(data);
                            }).error(function(data, status) {
                                console.log("Request failed " + status);
                            });

                }
            };
        }]);

var AppController = function($scope,DataSource) {

    var SOURCE_FILE = "timer.xml";

    xmlTransform = function(data) {
        console.log("transform data");
        var x2js = new X2JS();
        var json = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
        return json.TimerStatus;
    };

    setData = function(data) {
    console.log("setdata", data);
        $scope.dataSet = data;
    };

    DataSource.get(SOURCE_FILE,setData,xmlTransform);
};
```

Comment: what is your specific problem? As for passing xml to another window this is trivial javascript using `window.open()`.

Comment: True - I ended up doing    $window.open(url,'_blank');